# Bug with user removal?

Tags: support, reputation

I just lost 13 reputation points due to a user being removed.

It appears though that the [insert-here-the-user-who-shall-not-be-named] has not been removed. And equally strange is that I only gained 2 reputation through him or her because I upvoted their answer so how did I loose even more than that?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Your edit doesn't make a lot of sense to me - the user *isn't* currently suspended (so it does not appear as if they are), and the *"has not been removed"* is now left hanging in the air. Also, why should this post not link to the user OP is thinking has been removed?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: 1. Thanks, corrected. 2. It seems to be speculation / private information about a particular user that is irrelevant for OP's post. Even without knowing the particular user, the post makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loss through "User removed" has been 15 reputation points. This means someone who upvoted three of your questions or one question and one answer has been removed.

I don't know how you concluded that this should be the user you link to, but it evidently isn't - there is no way to tell for us ordinary users which user removal your reputation lass was caused by.

Comment: Oh Okay It looked in the interface as if the two were connected to me sorry.^^ I guess the losses and gains are always listed like that

Comment: FWIW even as a moderator I can't tell which user it was (unless I had been the moderator to delete the account and I happened to remember which one it was).